# HTTP Server - Serving up favicon.ico

Tags: java, http, web, server

I'm playing around setting up my own java http server to better understand http servers and what goes on under the hood of the web. I've developed a pretty simple server and have been able to serve both html pages as well as data in JSON form. Then I saw the browser (I'm using chrome but assuming it's the same for others) was sending a request for favicon.ico. I'm able to identify that request on my server, so I'm trying to serve up a random icon I downloaded and resized to 16x16 pixels in png format, as that's what the internet says the size needs to be. Here's my code, note it's not supposed to be anything professional, just something that will work for my basic educational purposes:

```
[set up ServerSocket and listen]
public static String err_header = "HTTP/1.1 500 ERR\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
public static String success_header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
public static String end_header = "\r\n\r\n";
while(true){
        try{
            System.out.println("Listening for new connections");
            clientSocket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String getLine = reader.readLine();//first line of HTTP request
            handleRequest(getLine,clientSocket);
        }//end of try
        catch(Exception e){
            [error stuff]
        }//end of catch
    }//end of while
```

HandleRequest method:

```
public static void handleRequest(String getLine,Socket clientSocket) throws Exception{
    if(getLine.substring(5,16).equals("favicon.ico")){
        List<String> iconTag = new ArrayList<String>();
        iconTag.add("\nContent-Type: image/png");
        handleFileRequest("[file]",iconTag,clientSocket);
    }//end of if
    else{
        handleFileRequest("[file]",clientSocket);
    }//end of else
}//end of handleRequest
```

handleFileRequest for images:

```
public static void handleFileRequest(String fileName,List<String> headerTags,Socket clientSocket) throws Exception{
    OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    out.write(success_header.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    Iterator<String> itr = headerTags.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        out.write(itr.next().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }//end of while
    out.write(end_header.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String readLine = "";
    while((readLine = read.readLine())!=null){
        out.write(readLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }//end of while
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}//end of handleFileRequest
```

And it appears to work, as the server sends the file, the browser shows the 200 OK response, but there's no favicon and when I filter network requests to just images, there is one image requested by the page being served but the favicon request is not listed there (the favicon request is in the "other" section). Similarly when clicking on the other image the image shows up on the preview, whereas that's not the case with the favicon request. Screenshot:

[image: favicon]

Meanwhile here's what the other image looks like, and it shows up in the page just fine:

[image: other image]

I also tried including the Content-Length header, but that didn't seem to make a difference. Am I missing something obvious?

Also just to clarify, I know I can include the favicon in the actual html page, the goal isn't to do it, but to understand how it works.

Comment: If you visit the url of the favicon directly, do you see it?

Comment: There's no url, I'm sending it over http as bytes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by any of that. You can see the url of the favicon in the HTTP request header in your screenshot. The browser is asking for it. That's how browsers get the favicon, by sending an HTTP request to get it. If the favicon is served correctly, then if you visit its URL directly, you should be able to see it.

Comment: So a separate http request is made? It makes the request to the server for the data. My server replies with the appropriate HTTP headers followed by the binary of the icon, not a link. Is the appropriate response to actually just be the url, and then chrome will make an additional http request to that link?

Comment: I went to the url in that screenshot. The response field is filled with the appropriate binary, but the image does not show up correctly in the browser.

Comment: If you visit the url of the favicon, can you see it or not? If yes, then it is served correctly, otherwise no. And to your other question, when you visit any website on the internet, the browser will make additional http requests based on the content: css files, image files in `<img/>` tags, script files in `<script/>` tags, and so on, and the favicon too. These resources all have their own urls, that's how the browser can request them. Visiting these urls return binary content, not "links".

Comment: Here's what shows up: [screenshot](https://i.gyazo.com/55f2813c919aef62cee08ce5443c35ec.png)

The image is not a white box so that is not the correct image, but the response appears to be the binary data of the PNG file.

Comment: I see. Perhaps the content is not served correctly. I'll do some experiments and try to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Reading binary files

It seems the content of the favicon is not served correctly.

I suspect this is most likely due to the way you read its content:

> ```
> while((readLine = read.readLine())!=null){
>     out.write(readLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));
> }
> ```

Reading binary content line by line is inappropriate,
because the concept of lines, and also UTF-8 encoding,
don't make sense in the context of binary files.
And you cannot read binary content correctly line by line this way,
because the `readLine` method of a `BufferedReader` doesn't return the full line, because it strips the newline from the end.
You cannot manually add a newline character because you cannot know what exactly it was.

Here's a simpler and correct way to read the content of a binary file:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file"));
```

Once you have this, it's easy to produce a correct file header with the content length, using the value of `bytes.length`.

#### What happens when you visit a page in a browser

It seems it will be good for you if we clarify a few things.

When you open a URL in a browser,
the browser sends a GET request to the web server to download the content of the original URL that you have specified.

Once it has the page content, it will send further GET requests:

- Fetch a favicon if it doesn't have one already. The location of this may be specified in the HTML document, or else the browser will try to fetch `SERVERNAME/favicon.ico` by default
- Fetch the images specified in `src` attribute of any (valid) `<img/>` tags in the document
- Fetch the style sheets specified in `href` attribute of any (valid) `<style/>` tags in the document
- ... and similarly for `<script/>` tags, and so on...

The favicon is purely cosmetic, to show in browser tab titles,
the other resources are essential for rendering a page.
They are not essential in text-based browsers like lynx,
such browsers will obviously not fetch these resources.

This is the explanation for why the favicon is requested, and how.

#### How does a web server serve files?

In the most basic case, serving a file has two important components:

1. Produce an appropriate HTTP header: each line in the header is in `name: value` format, and each line must end with `\n`.
   There must be at least a `Content-type` header.
   The header must be terminated by a blank line.
2. After the blank line that terminates the header,
   the content can be anything, even binary.
   To illustrate with an example,
   consider the `curl` command, which dumps the content of a url to standard output.
   If you run `curl url-to-some-html-file`,
   you will see the content of the html file.
   If you run `curl url-to-some-image-file`,
   you will see the content of the image file.
   It will be unreadable, and your terminal will probably make funny noises.
   You can redirect the output to a file with `curl url-to-some-image-file > image.png`,
   and that will give you an image file,
   binary content,
   that you can open in any image viewer tool.

In short, serving files is really just printing a header on `stdout`,
then printing a blank line to terminate the header,
then printing the content on `stdout`.

#### Debugging the serving of an image

An easy way to debug that an image is correctly served is to save the URL to a file using `curl`,
and then verify that the saved file and the original file are identical,
for example using the `cmp` command:

```
curl -o file url-to-favicon
cmp file /path/to/original
```

The output of `cmp` should be empty.
This command only produces output if it finds a difference in the two files.

#### Implementing a simple HTTP server

Instead of using a `ServerSocket`,
here's a drastically simpler way to implement an HTTP server:

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(1234), 0);

server.createContext("/favicon.ico", t -> {
  byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/favicon"));
  t.sendResponseHeaders(200, bytes.length);
  try (OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody()) {
    os.write(bytes);
  }
});

server.createContext("/", t -> {
  Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/index"), charset);

  t.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);

  try (OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody()) {
    for (String line : lines) {
      os.write((line + "\n").getBytes(charset));
    }
  }
});

server.start();
```

Comment: This makes a ton of sense, I'm assuming my logic is also losing newlines in the HTML pages, but since that doesn't alter the content I didn't notice it. With this change it is correctly calculating the number of bytes, and now the browser sees it as a png file so that's an improvement, but it still is not showing the actual image in the favicon location or in the preview in the chrome developer tools (and when I navigate to the url the actual icon does not show up).

Comment: @zachvac I added more explanations in (see several new sections in the middle of my post) to help you debug this.

Comment: Thanks, that worked :)

It had something to do with the encoding, as what I was doing was taking the byte array, creating a new String, and then calling getBytes("UTF-8") on it. I'm going to research what that line is actually doing, but when I just sent the raw byte array that worked and the image is showing up as expected. Thank you so much for all the help :)